# Java Type Generic as Argument for GSON

Tags: java, generics, gson

In GSON to get a list of objects you do

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type token = new TypeToken<List<MyType>>(){}.getType();
return gson.fromJson(json, token);
```

It works great, but I want to go further and have MyType parametrized so I can have a common function to parse list of objects with this code

```
// the common function 
public <T> List<T> fromJSonList(String json, Class<T> type) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
  return gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
}

// the call
List<MyType> myTypes = parser.fromJSonList(jsonString, MyType.class);
```

Sadly returns an array of StringMaps, not the type. T is being interpreted as another generic type, not my type. Any workaround ?

Comment: Maybe these links can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356583/can-i-reflectively-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-java http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t593591-how-to-create-an-instance-of-type-t.html http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html In the second link, they suggest a factory method. Hmm... I'm not sure if using ? instead of T could solve the problem.

Answer (score 64):

Since `gson 2.8.0`, you can use [`TypeToken#getParametized((Type rawType, Type... typeArguments))`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/37ed0fcbd7930df0aad9f5068c608e4465413877/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java#L341) to create the `typeToken`, then `getType()` should do the trick.

For example:

```
TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, myType.class).getType();
```

Answer (score 42):

Generics work at compile-time. The reason super-type tokens work, is because (anonymous) inner classes can access the type arguments to their generic superclasses (superinterfaces), which in turn are stored directly in the bytecode metadata.

Once your .java source file is compiled, the type parameter `<T>` is obviously thrown away. Since it is not known at compile time, it cannot be stored in bytecode, so it's erased and Gson can't read it.

**UPDATE**

After newacct's answer, I tried to implement what he suggested in his option 2, ie implementing a `ParameterizedType`. The code looks like this (here is a basic [test](http://pastebin.com/PV6cP9jc)):

```
class ListOfSomething<X> implements ParameterizedType {

    private Class<?> wrapped;

    public ListOfSomething(Class<X> wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] {wrapped};
    }

    public Type getRawType() {
        return List.class;
    }

    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

the purpose of this code, is to be used inside `getFromJsonList()`:

```
public List<T> fromJsonList(String json, Class<T> klass) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, new ListOfSomething<T>(klass));
}
```

Even if the technique works and is indeed very clever (I didn't know it and I would have never thinked of it), this is the final accomplishment:

```
List<Integer> list = new Factory<Integer>()
         .getFromJsonList(text, Integer.class)
```

instead of

```
List<Integer> list = new Gson().fromJson(text,
         new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}.getType());
```

To me, all this wrapping in useless, even if I agree that `TypeToken`s make the code look nasty :P

Comment: It is. The key point to understand is that in order for the *super-type token machinary* to work, we must create a ficticious anonymous class, ie a piece of bytecode that has even its own `Outer.$N.class` file. This is the trick that makes `TypeToken` work, but can't really work in your case, because when the supplied method source is compiled, the `Class<T>` argument fo `fromJSonList` is erased

Comment: It's not "erased" in the `Type`. Rather, the generic argument will be stored as a `TypeVariable` rather than a `Class`

Comment: @newacct maybe you misunderstood that phrase. I mean, inside `fonrJsonList()`, the `type` argument is a raw `Class`.

Comment: @Raffaele: but they are not using `type` to construct the `collectionType`. In fact, they are not using `type` at all

Comment: @newacct indeed, because OP introduced it just as a way to match the signature with the return type. But then he couldn't use it inside the method body, that's why asked this question. And I think it's correct to state that there's no way to access `T` because it's erased. Where do you think is the flaw?

Comment: @Raffaele: but at runtime we do have the class object for `T` -- it is `type`. It's just that at compile time we don't have it.

Comment: @newacct We all agree on this. Maybe you are questioning the inaccuracy of the phrase *...the Class argument to fromJSonList() is erased* in my first comment. Yeah, that's very badly phrased and uses wrong terms. Maybe I should have written that `Class<T>` is not reifiable, but this doesn't really help in a comment. It's an unfortunate sentence, wrong and misleading. But comments cannot be edited

Comment: Souldn't `getRawType` return `ListOfSomething.class` instead? Otherwise thanks, you saved my ass today :)

Comment: @Raffaele What if i have to use `List<T>` inside another Generic class lets say `Response<T extends EntityBase>` which also contains other properties. I am so sorry if i sound too noobish, i recently shifted from C# to java and it is literally over my head right now...

Comment: You can use the code in this answer if the type is known at runtime . If you need further help, ask your own question along with the demo code

Comment: What is the namespace for Factory<Integer>?

Comment: I have a a class that wraps backend calls that retreive both single items and lists of items. This class is then used for several different types of objects. This answer IS useful because this technique removes the need to supply both a Class<T> and a TypeToken<List<T>> parameter to my class, because I can create a ListOfSomething *from* the former. Makes my code cleaner and less error-prone.

Answer (score 30):

```
public static final <T> List<T> getList(final Class<T[]> clazz, final String json)
{
    final T[] jsonToObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz);

    return Arrays.asList(jsonToObject);
}
```

Example:

```
getList(MyClass[].class, "[{...}]");
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Comment: How to use for getting Singel Object of <T>

Comment: Good answer, but be aware that the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is a read-only wrapper for the array. It's not an `ArrayList`. You can't add or modify items.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the full code base on great answer from @oldergod

```
public <T> List<T> fromJSonList(String json, Class<T> myType) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type collectionType = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, myType).getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
}
```

Using

```
List<MyType> myTypes = parser.fromJSonList(jsonString, MyType.class);
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 6):

I've taken [Raffaele's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14139700/1502352) approach one step further and generified the class, so that it works with every class A, where B is a non-parameterized class. Might be useful for Sets and other Collections.

```
    public class GenericOf<X, Y> implements ParameterizedType {

    private final Class<X> container;
    private final Class<Y> wrapped;

    public GenericOf(Class<X> container, Class<Y> wrapped) {
        this.container = container;
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[]{wrapped};
    }

    public Type getRawType() {
        return container;
    }

    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Kotlin** you can simply use this function:

```
inline fun <reified T> fromJson(json: String): T {
  return Gson().fromJson(json, object: TypeToken<T>(){}.type)
}
```

and use it like

```
val myTypes: List<MyType> = fromJson(jsonString);
```

It will parse any object including gereric types as List. Keyword `inline` and `reified` ensures that type will not be erased.

> For detail info I can recommend this [Medium post](https://medium.com/@imstudio/android-kotlin-how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin-e2b17c0ac24c)

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered in previous questions. Basically, there are 2 options:

1. Pass the `Type` in from the calling site. The calling code will use `TypeToken` or whatever to construct it.
2. Construct a `Type` corresponding to the parameterized type yourself. This will require you to write a class that implements `ParameterizedType`

Comment: I think option 1 completely defeats the purpose of `fromJsonList()` - option 2 is very clever instead. Is [this](http://pastebin.com/PV6cP9jc) what you mean?

Comment: @Raffaele: perhaps. Or you can copy the source of ParameterizedTypeImpl (used internally by many Java libraries) from the Internet

Answer (score 3):

If programming in kotlin, we can use `reified type parameter` in inline function

```
class GenericGson {

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Any> Gson.fromJsonTokenType(jsonString: String): T {
            val type = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
            return this.fromJson(jsonString, type)
        }

        inline fun <reified T : Any> Gson.fromJsonType(jsonString: String): T = this.fromJson(jsonString, T::class.java)

        inline fun <reified T : Any> fromJsonTokenType(jsonString: String): T = Gson().fromJsonTokenType(jsonString)

        inline fun <reified T : Any> fromJsonType(jsonString: String): T = Gson().fromJsonType(jsonString)
    }
}
```

And use like below in your code

```
val arrayList = GenericGson.fromJsonTokenType<ArrayList<Person>>(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin "ListOfSomething" solution that worked for me:

```
fun <T: Any> getGsonList(json: String, kclass: KClass<T>) : List<T> {

    return getGsonInstance().fromJson<List<T>>(json, ListOfSomething<T>(kclass.java))
}


internal class ListOfSomething<X>(wrapped: Class<X>) : ParameterizedType {

    private val wrapped: Class<*>

    init {
        this.wrapped = wrapped
    }

    override fun getActualTypeArguments(): Array<Type> {
        return arrayOf<Type>(wrapped)
    }

    override fun getRawType(): Type {
        return ArrayList::class.java
    }

    override fun getOwnerType(): Type? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In  kotlin simple use for example:

**Get places function**

`fun getPlaces<T> (jsonString : String, clazz: Class<T>) : T {
    val places : T = Gson().fromJson(jsonString,clazz)
    return places
}`

**Then you can use as:**

```
val places = getPlaces(Array<Place>::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static <T> T getObject(String gsonStr) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken< T>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(gsonStr,
                collectionType);
    }
```

When use:

```
Class1 class1=  getObject(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for everything.
e.g. map which has a key and value generic.

```
CustomType type = new CustomType(Map.class, String.class, Integer.class);
```

So no more TokenType.

```
class CustomType implements ParameterizedType {
    private final Class<?> container;
    private final Class<?>[] wrapped;

    @Contract(pure = true)
    public CustomType(Class<?> container, Class<?>... wrapped) {
        this.container = container;
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return this.wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return this.container;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T> List<T> fromJSonList(String json) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
  return gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
}

//Just call
List<MyType> myTypes = parser.<MyType>fromJSonList(jsonString);
```