# DataProvider returning Object[][] does not match argument type

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, data-structures, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a TestNG dataProvider that needs to return an Object[][]. Here is how I get this object array I am returning.

The test method looks like this:

```
public void testUser(UserModel testData)
```

1. Get the parent "Test" method's argument type. (Method m.getParameterTypes()[0].newInstance) and add this to an Object array. (It will add UserModel object type to that array) - This works fine.
2. Pass this Object[] into a method that reads from a json file and builds it into the object type. Then this method returns an array of objects (Object[]) of that object type based on the json file. - This works fine.
3. From there I convert the Object[] returned into a 2D object array. It looks like this: Object[size][1]. -  It builds the object[][] fine, but the objects may lose their type here.

For example: the array is made up of two objects. it will look like this.
Object[1][1] = Object[0]
Object[2][1] = Object[1]

4. I then return this object to be used and it throws the following exception:

   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

I have tried to return the single Object[] that the method returns as the following:

```
return new Object[][] { singleObjectArray };
```

But this just ignores the test cases because it's not returning it properly.

How can I make sure that the object array is returning the correct types. I just want to be able to handle arrays of objects from json and have the test case run that many times.

Here is the DataProvider code.

```
   @DataProvider(name = "DataProviderArray")
protected static Object[][] getCoreDataProviderArray(Method superMethod,
                                                  ITestContext context) {
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        objectList.add(superMethod.getParameterTypes()[0].newInstance());

        Object[] objectArray = objectList.toArray();
        JsonUtils jsonUtils = new JsonUtils(TEST_DATA_LOCATION
                + context.getName() + JSON_EXTENSION);

        Object[] newUsers = jsonUtils.createArrayOfObjectsFromJsonFile(objectArray);

        Object [][] objects = new Object[newUsers.length][1];

        for (int i = 0; i < newUsers.length; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(newUsers, i, objects[i], 0, 1);
        }

        return objects;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeInterruptionException("Could not return object for "
                + superMethod.getParameterTypes()[0] + "...");
    }
}
```

and JsonUtils class:

```
    public Object[] createArrayOfObjectsFromJsonFile(Object[] objectToCreate) {
    gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    return gson.fromJson(reader, objectToCreate.getClass());

}
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `objects[i][0] = newUsers[i]` instead of `System.arraycopy(newUsers, i, objects[i], 0, 1);`?

Comment: That works the same. It is still failing with that same exception. Can't quite tell why though...

Comment: You should add some debug prints on types and content. If you can share a runnable sample on github, I will be able to have a look on it

Comment: @JulienHerr Thank you, here is the project link; https://github.com/Dominic-Pace/AutoCoreCommons 

 -- please refer to org.autocore.java.commons.utils.BaseCoreTest for the data provider class.

 -- please refer to org.autocore.java.commons.utils.JsonUtils for the json creation. 

 -- please refer to test package org.autocore.java.unit.commons.utils.JsonUtilsTwo for the test case that is utilizing the data provider!

 -- please refer to test.resources.testsuites.JsonSuite.xml to run the suite...Keep in mind that the json file is referenced from the test name in this suite file. Thanks!

Comment: Edit: It seems that gson.toJson in the JsonUtils is converting the specified object type into LinkedTreeMap and adding two object maps to the object array.

Comment: Ok, it looks you got it. Try by converting one by one instead of the array. And you can use a listener/iterator instead of a 2d array for the data provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
@DataProvider(name = "DataProviderArray")
protected static Iterator<Object[]> getCoreDataProviderArray(Method superMethod, ITestContext context) {

  Class<?> type = superMethod.getParameterTypes()[0];     
  JsonUtils jsonUtils = new JsonUtils(TEST_DATA_LOCATION
    + context.getName() + JSON_EXTENSION);  
  List<Object> newUsers;
  try {
    newUsers = jsonUtils.createObjectsFromJsonFile(type);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeInterruptionException("Could not return object for "
                + superMethod.getParameterTypes()[0] + "...");
  }

  List<Object[]> objects = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Object user : newUsers) {
    objects.add(new Object[]{user});
  }
  return objects.iterator();
}
```

Then, the harder part will be JsonUtils with something like:

```
public List<Object> createObjectsFromJsonFile(Class<?> objectToCreate) {
  gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
  return gson.fromJson(reader, /*<appropriate type array from objectToCreate>*/);
}
```

But the answer is somewhere here: [Java Type Generic as Argument for GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139437/java-type-generic-as-argument-for-gson)

Comment: Great! :) Then could you accept/upvote the response?